# Calling method of another parent of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible for a class to call a method of another class through `super()` if they are both parents of the same class?

```
class A:
    def a(self, x):
        return x * 2

class B:
    def b(self, x):
        tmp = super().a(x)  # <---
        return tmp + 2

class C(A, B):
    def c(self):
        return super().b(20)

print(C().c())
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I thought this would work because `C.mro()` is `[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>]` (so `A` is in it) and it's the callee's MRO that's supposed to be defining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not quite like this.

A class's MRO is a total order over all ancestors of a class, including ancestors with no superclass relation between them. `A` and `B` aren't treated equally; `A` comes first in `C`'s MRO (required because `A` was listed as a base class before `B` in the class statement), so the `super` lookup will start after `B` in `C`'s MRO and skip past `A` entirely.

For your `b` method's `super` lookup to work, `C` would have had to be created as `class C(B, A): ...`. Depending on your goal, you might instead want to just replace all those `super().whatever` calls with `self.whatever`, if you don't actually want the override-skipping behavior of `super`. If you do want override-skipping, but you want it in a way where `A` and `B` are treated symmetrically, you may have to build your own mechanism for that.

Comment: Note that even if it works, it's at best a confusing, and at worst a *bad*, design. They inherit from *nothing*, yet assume there will be an `a` method available somewhere  (but not on a subclass, cause `super()` says no). Using `super` is typically to delegate to the parent implementation of the same method, but they use it to call *other* methods (as written, they could just call `self.a()` after all, since they don't need to bypass subclass implementations).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just use `tmp = self.a(x)` and it should work as expected. Using `super()` is for accessing base classes. Here you just need an instance variable.

Comment: This is probably what you actually want in 99% of cases, but it's not equivalent, since it doesn't necessarily invoke A's implementation of the method.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to imagine a situation where this is genuinely something you would want to do. Such a method can only be called on objects which are instances of both `A` and `B`. @user2357112 has given the strictly correct answer to this question, but as pointed out in a comment, the solution using `super()` is not good design. So I will give an answer in case this isn't an abstract language-lawyer puzzler, and you (or others with the same question) are writing real code.

---

If `C` is the only class which will extend both `A` and `B`, then the simplest thing you can do is write the `b` method in class `C`.

Otherwise, if multiple classes might extend both `A` and `B`, then you can declare a "base" class for all such extensions, put the `b` method there, and make other classes inherit from that instead of `A` and `B` separately:

```py
class A:
    def a(self, x):
        return x * 2

class B:
    pass

class A_and_B(A, B):
    def b(self, x):
        tmp = self.a(x)
        return tmp + 2

class C(A_and_B):
    def c(self):
        return self.b(20)
```

This way, instances of `B` which are not instances of `A` won't have the `b` method, which is desirable because the method can't be called on non-instances of `A` anyway.

The code above calls whichever implementation of `a` the object has, which could be overridden by a subclass. If you absolutely must call the `A` class's implementation of `a`, not some overridden version of it, then you can invoke `A.a` directly:

```py
        tmp = A.a(self, x)
```

This is still bad design, but not quite as bad as hacking `super()` to call a method on a class which is not actually a superclass.

Comment: Thank you for the practical advice! I ended up with the straighforward `class A`, `class B(A)`, and  `class C(B)`. Initially I was indeed looking for a solution for the real code but then it grew into a puzzle as I realized the code didn't behave as I thought it should.

Comment: Yes, if there's no need to have any instances of B that aren't also instances of A, then making B a subclass of A is the right call.